# unregister return key and change it action

Tags: javascript, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to make `KEY_RETURN` in Samsung smart tv (tizen) do something else than close the app.

I tried some code snippets I found but non of them worked.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Show us just of the code snippets you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring the pop-up menu, as when you put the app for certification you this is application guideline to bring pop-up to end user.

On pop-up you can then add require action to exit or resume (OK or CANCEL).
https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenSampleGuide/tizen3881/index.html

Also use event.preventDefault in the case for the return.

Answer (score 0):

As wrote @Stallion. You can use event.preventDefault and set other behavior for return key. But you should know, that unexpected behavior can be problem for QA procedure.